# Can't install EncFS

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, storage, lubuntu, encfs

I have a 32GB SSD in my laptop and PCManFM 1.2.0 is showing 14.5GB free at the bottom right corner of the screen in the status bar.

[image]

However, when I try to install an application such as `encfs`, I get a message saying, "out of space"...

Why is that?

I am using Lutuntu 14.04.

Here is the output I get when trying to install encfs:

```
oshiro@laptop:~$ sudo aptitude install encfs
[sudo] password for oshiro: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  encfs libboost-serialization1.54.0{a} libboost-system1.54.0{a} librlog5{a} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  initramfs-tools linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/38.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 2,662 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-50-generic but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:       
1)     linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  encfs libboost-serialization1.54.0{a} libboost-system1.54.0{a} librlog5{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic{a} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  initramfs-tools linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/436 kB of archives. After unpacking 114 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
(Reading database ... 279919 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic (3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-50-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-50-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-50-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-50-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-50-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_eIhOa4/lib/modules/3.16.0-50-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_eIhOa4/lib/modules/3.16.0-50-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-50-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-50-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
find: ‘standard output’: Broken pipe
find: write error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 1 cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
find: ‘standard output’: Broken pipe
find: write error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 1 cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic
 initramfs-tools

oshiro@laptop:~$
```

Comment: It's is only happening when you try to install encfs? Reading the logs I have the feeling that the error start when remove the _linux-image-extra_ pkg because a "fatal" with an unexisting file in /boot. I suggest to check what's happening in the boot partition (or directory if you've set all in one). Try "man df" and see what this command can do for you.

Comment: If it's not a partition out of space (/tmp ?) I'm suspecting your software sources are causing errors. Tried resetting them to defaults?